# Varnish as a Proxy for Nginx on port 443

Tags: magento, nginx, proxy, varnish

I have my Nginx and Varnish working fine on my server. Varnish is listening to port 80 and Nginx 8080.

However, I had to run the whole website over SSL 443 (I'm using Magento).

I was trying to create a proxy and make the 443 request to go to Varnish by using this config https://gist.github.com/medinadato/572e931796ec8e38939db25fe73b0552. Please note the lines 1-4 where I set Varnish and 27 (location / {) where I redirect the requests.

The problem with this set up is a infinite loop that happens when Nginx tries to redirect the request.

I've tried the fix it on the lines 93-97 and 37 but it's still happening.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what is happening without seeing the Varnish vcl. One thing you could try is to remove everything in the Nginx config from line 43 downward. Run either varnishlog and or varnishncsa to verify that the varnish server is in fact receiving the request from nginx.